# Future of Mobile Development

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I was reading [an article based on Mobile Development in 2020](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8157043.stm) and run into such a pessimistic claim:

> "But the economics are a different
>   story. The ratio of those developers
>   who will fail is about 90%; they will
>   simply not make a return on their
>   investment or make a good enough
>   living at this,"  said Mr Laurs.
>
> He said that will result in developers
>   taking their talent elsewhere and also
>   slow down the rate of growth in
>   applications.

Do you think it will be just another hype so that the majority of the developers will have to switch to something else? or What might be the driving force behind this?

Ps: I hope my **argumentative** question doesn't violate SO rules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think his definition of "fail" is a bit too broad. I've worked on a lot of projects that I've never received any direct return on my investment and I haven't considered any of those to be "failures". Sure, I didn't get filthy rich from them but I gained a lot of experience that I'm able to put down on a resume or convey during an interview. I think he's just being overly pessimistic about how the industry works.

**EDIT**

I read through the article some more. I do think he's right that the amount of new apps flowing in will die down but that's just because the market will be saturated with all the obvious ports. As with any new web technology it's a "fastest gun" race to make IRC clients, tetris games and of course, pac man. I still feel he's acting like this is a tragedy of some kind. I think this will be a much more exciting time when we'll see developers with immensely creative ideas finally come out of the woodwork when they're not afraid of their applications getting lost in the crowd.

Answer (score 2):

It's the basic concept of supply and demand. There's a huge demand for mobile applications now, with the mobile devices evolving to a state that you can actually do stuff (mostly bigger display and higher processing power). It is not a market that is mature now, so there are a lot of opportunities - explaining the big number of players joining the game.

As the market matures, big players are going to stand out, making the competition tougher, so I think it's save to say the single players will have a harder time competing.

The market is going to stabilize at a point in time. For now it's growing fast and there is still place for it

Answer (score 1):

I dont really see the hype over mobile development. So far (with some exceptions) the overwhelming majority of applications I've seen can be split into 2 categories - games / toys, and apps that are simply front ends onto existing websites (for example the facebook app).

Other than games, the number of applications that actually do anything in their own right is astoundingly low (london tube map applications are the only ones the spring to mind), and the majority of the rest of the apps very little user experience improvement beyond basic "offline mode" functionality.

Personally I see the majority of future of mobile development as being web based, with improments to mobile browsers and offline browsing. If the in-browser experience is good enough, and users are able browse downloaded cached copies of websites then the owners of those sites wont need to invest in mobile development across the 3-4 different platforms available, which is comparatively more expensive than web development.

The exception of course being games and toys - the web isnt really a suitable platform for these. At the same time the sorts of users who are going to buy games are probably the same people who already own smartphones, so I cant really see this market growing massively without innovation on the part of the game authors.

The other exception being applications that require access to things like the camera or microphone (and to a certain extent GPS - there is no reason why location information cant be sent to websites by the browser). However once I cant see there being a huge number of applications that fall into this category.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your assertion that non-Internet-connected mobile applications are necessarily toys.  There are many practical non-game applications that work extremely well in a mobile context: calculation applications of various types, task management tools, calendars, data logging and visualization, encrypted data storage, document readers, etc.  This also neglects the potential for connection to, and control of, external hardware.

Comment: All I said is that the majority of the apps available at the moment fall into the category of games or toys (e.g. the iPint application). There are also a number of "useful" applications on the market (applications calculators, calendars etc...) but most mobile platforms have applications that fulfil the needs of most users for these tasks built in.

Comment: Hmm, to reitterate - I never said that there arent a number of applications other than toys that wont work extremely well on mobile platorms, I do think however that this market is far more limited than people realise, and that a number of current applications that fall into this category would work just as well as mobile web sites.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser doesn't win, Android is close behind. Camera designers, threatened by cellphones with good lenses, started putting Android on cameras, so now you can run Instagram on a Nikon. Does that make Nikon a computer company now? Does it even matter?

There are Android refrigerators, car stereos, watches, televisions, even headphones. Some complain that the UI is too complicated because it can do too much, but that's missing the point. The UI layer can always be simplified. If Android is running underneath, the platform will dominate.

It's going to get even more complicated. PC manufacturers are looking at the burgeoning tablet world and feeling left out. Their solution is to run Android on Windows and let people use their Android apps on their desktops, too. Some just run the stock Android emulators used by programmers, but others are looking beyond that to create brands like "PC Plus." Once Android takes over the PC, it may combine with the browser to push Windows native apps into a distant third place for mindshare on the box